# how can I know what index is an html element in its parent children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I chose an HTML element

and I want to select its next sibling,

but if it's the last child i want to select the first child.

the `+` selector won't do this.

How can i get this child index using css selectors?

Comment: You seem to be asking two entirely different questions here. Can you make up your mind what exactly it is you want to do, and with what language?

Comment: to get the next sibling, use `nextElementSibling`, to check if it is the last element or not, compare it against the `lastChild`, and then use `firstChild` to get the first element.